# How do I apply regex in xslt 2.0 with analyze-string component correctly

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a question regarding xslt 2.0 transformation and the analyze-string component:

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<!-->Template for properties<-->
<xsl:template match="UserValue">

    <xsl:variable name="TITLE" select="./@title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="VALUE" select="./@value"/>

    <xsl:analyze-string select="$VALUE" regex="^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$">

        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <Property>  
                <Title><xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/></Title>
                <Value>Date:<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>Time:<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></Value>
            </Property>
        </xsl:matching-substring>

        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <!-->Set title and value property<-->
            <Property>
                <Title><xsl:value-of select="$TITLE"/></Title>
                <Value><xsl:value-of select="$VALUE"/></Value>
            </Property>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

There are datetime strings in following format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

I used the **`^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$`** expression to extract two groups. The first group with date and the second group with time and I wanted to add them like it is in the stylesheet.

Now what happens is, that only the **non-matching-substring** block is executed and not the **matching-substring** block. I also tried it with the xsl when element and there the matching works but it is not the way I want to do it and also I would like to use the `regex-group()` function as it would perfectly fit my needs.

I cannot find the error I may have done here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete XML input sample to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of curly braces in the `select` represent [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates), which means the expression inside the curly braces will be executed to get a value, rather than output literally. So, effectively your regex is being treated as if it was this....

```
^(\d4-\d2-\d2)T(\d2:\d2:\d2)$
```

To prevent Attribute Value Templates being used, you have to use double-curly braces

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$VALUE" regex="^(\d{{4}}-\d{{2}}-\d{{2}})T(\d{{2}}:\d{{2}}:\d{{2}})$">
```

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation! That exactly solved the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Now that your question has been answered, consider a completely different approach that takes advantage of XSLT 2.0 native ability to:

- recognize a string that represents dateTime; and
- cast a dateTime to date and/or time.

without requiring regex.

```
<xsl:template match="UserValue">
    <Property>  
        <Title>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
        </Title>
        <Value>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@value castable as xs:dateTime">
                    <xsl:variable name="dt" select="xs:dateTime(@value)" /> 
                    <xsl:text>Date:</xsl:text>  
                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($dt)" />
                    <xsl:text>Time:</xsl:text>  
                    <xsl:value-of select="xs:time($dt)" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Value>
    </Property>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/a9Gixn